# how make empty file with desired size on x86 systems by php

Tags: php, makefile, x86, fseek

I wnat to make an empty file with desired size on windows server 2003 x86 by php. A file larger than 2GB example 2.67Gb - 2870348740 bytes.

I use this code but makes a file with size of 1.89GB - 2040109466 bytes.

What I must do now ?

```
$size = 2870348740;
$fp = fopen('fileLocation/test.x', 'wb'); // open in write mode.
$eachpart = floor(1.9 * 1024*1024*1024); // 1.9 Gbyte to byte
$parts = ceil($size/$eachpart);
for ($i=0; $i<$parts; $i++){
    if ($i == $parts-1) $offset = $size - (($parts-1)*$eachpart) -1;
    else $offset = $eachpart;

    fseek($fp, $offset ,SEEK_CUR); // seek from current position
}
fwrite($fp,0); // write a dummy char at SIZE position
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Actually, a file that has a size greater than `0` is not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
file_put_contents('mybigfatfile.txt', str_repeat("\0",2*1024*1024*1024));
```

---

Update

you can build the string also on x86 system with

```
$kb = str_repeat("\0",1024);
$mb = str_repeat($kb,1024);
$gb = str_repeat($mb,1024);
file_put_contents('mybigfatfile.txt', str_repeat($gb,2));
```

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis, @gafreax!

Comment: @gafreax in str_repeat second parameter must be **greater than 0** and _2*1024*1024*1024_ in **x86 systems** is out of range of positive numbers and give us a **negative number**. so str_repeat show us an error !!

Comment: thanks  @localheinz, I've added missinig parenthesis

Comment: @saeid what error did you see? Are you on win system?

Comment: yes I'm in windows server 2003 x86. error: **Warning: str_repeat(): Second argument has to be greater than or equal to 0**

Comment: @gafreax your new updated code shows another error. memory overflow error. msg: **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1073741825 bytes)**

Comment: Doesn't this actually write all those bytes, instead of making a sparse file?  i.e. it will take hundreds of thousands of times longer.

Answer (score 0):

I extended @gafreax solution and maked this code and problem solved.

thanks to @gafreax .

```
function makeFile($size,$dest){
    $eachpart = 100 * 1024*1024; // 100Mb
    $parts = ceil($size/$eachpart);
    for ($i=0; $i<$parts; $i++){
        if ($i == $parts-1) $offset = $size - (($parts-1)*$eachpart);
        else $offset = $eachpart;

        file_put_contents($dest, str_repeat("\0",$offset),FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```